# gradlew app:assembleRelease Error in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

My android/build.gradle

gradlew bundleRelease this command is working but gradlew app:assembleRelease this is not working

```js
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } 
    
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```

my Error:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:packagingOptionsCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :react-native-community_progress-bar-android.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No matching variant of project :react-native-community_progress-bar-android was found. The con
> sumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attrib
> utes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'packagingOptions' but:
> - Variant 'debugApiElements' capability DevreAnalizi:react-native-community_progress-bar-and
> roid:unspecified declares an API of a component:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.an
> droid.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as w
> ell as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'packagingOptions'
> - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability DevreAnalizi:react-native-community_progress-bar
> -android:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.an
> droid.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as w
> ell as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'packagingOptions'
> - Variant 'releaseApiElements' capability DevreAnalizi:react-native-community_progress-bar-a
> ndroid:unspecified declares an API of a component:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.an
> droid.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as
> well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'packagingOptions'
> - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability DevreAnalizi:react-native-community_progress-b
> ar-android:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.an
> droid.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as
> well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'packagingOptions'

Comment: Have you installed `react-native-community_progress-bar-android`?

Comment: no, do i need to download

Comment: Run `npm i @react-native-community/progress-bar-android`. Also you have a typo I guess, it should be `@react-native-community/progress-bar-android` and not `react-native-community_progress-bar-android`